# Four Divs with each other not showing up correctly in Safari

Tags: html, css

Here is the CodePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLDpj

Its working fine on Chrome, FF, IE11 but when testing on Safari, it doesn't.

Any ideas why?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="header" style="display:flex; -webkit-flex: 1; -ms-flex: 1; flex: 1; background-color:#004973; color:#fff;">
  <div class="logo" style="min-width:225px; overflow:hidden; height:54px; padding:15px; float:left; background-color:#060">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="225" height="47" style="max-width:none;">
  </div>
  <div class="search" style="width:100%; float:none; height:54px; padding:15px; background-color:#900;">
    <input name="" type="text" class="searchfield" value="Search Drug or Health Plan" style="height:30px; width:98%; padding:10px; box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border box;">
  </div>
  <div class="account" style="float:none; min-width:350px; height:54px; padding:15px; background-color:#00F;">
    Action Links here...
  </div>
  <div class="notify" style="min-width:70px; float:none; padding:15px;">
    <div class="notifynum">5</div>
    Notifications </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that pixel actual length and other css property don't work same in every browser. Just load different css for safari browser and else default for the other with JavaScript in your header section. And do different css formatting in  each css file for the div. The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var browser=navigator.userAgent;
if (browser.lastIndexOf("Safari")>=5)
{
var callbackFunc = function(){
//alert("WELCOME to Safari"); 
};

var head = document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0];
var fileref=document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");

fileref.setAttribute("href", "style_Safari.css");
fileref.onload = callbackFunc();
head.insertBefore( fileref, head.firstChild );
}

else
{
var callbackFunc = function(){
//alert("WELCOME others"); 
};
var head = document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0];
var fileref=document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", "style.css");
fileref.onload = callbackFunc();
head.insertBefore( fileref, head.firstChild );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that i had to use correct FLEX property for Safari, which is: **`display: -webkit-box;`**

Found this snippet very useful for all browsers:

```
.page-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
 }
```

I just assigned the above `page-wrap` class to the `.header` div and it worked!